# XSLT:How to sub string address field without split/cut the word in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Need to substring address without split/cutting the word. (we can take space as identifier)

Address1- should be 0-10 characters (if we got last space 30th char then remaining data should go to next  field)

Address2- should be 11-20 characters

Address3- should be 21-40 characters

please help me on this.
example:

Address:#1-20 Nearbridge road opposite marina bay, Singapore

Address1:#1-20 (1-10, but Nearbridge has no space, it should go to next field)
Address2:Nearbridge
Address3:road opposite marina

Comment: Do you use XSLT 2 or later where XPath 2 provides the `tokenize` function and XSLT the `xsl:analyze-string` element or XPath 3 the `analyze-string` function? Or, if you use an XSLT 1 processor, have you checked with it supports EXSLT's `tokenize`?

Comment: i am using 2.0. i have tried tokenize option like below: <xsl:value-of select="tokenize($address,'\ ')"/>. no luck

Answer (score 0):

Use substring, substring-before and substring-after. These are explained well here:

[XSL substring and indexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327232/xsl-substring-and-indexof)

If you want to use a space as a delimiter, the process depends on the address structure.

eg input:

```
<address>1 high st bigcity</address>
```

This xslt will return the number:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
<!-- returns '1'-->
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(address,' ')" />
<!-- returns rest of the address: 'high st Bigcity-->
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(address,' ')" />
<!-- returns 'high'-->
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(address,' '),' ')" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

if you have specific output formatting issues, please edit the question to include example input and your desired output.

Comment: i am looking sub string should not split/cut the word.  we need to use space as identifier.

Comment: edited based on your comment. Sample input and output expected would help.

Comment: still how can i do substring?

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="substring(address,0,10)" />. This will return the substring starting at 0 and have a length of 10